# ListView onItemSelected Listener not working

Tags: java, android, listview, layout-inflater

I was having some problem when trying to set on item selected listener of listview inside a popup window. Here is my codes:

```
private void openPopUp() {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                    context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_attendee_pop,
            null);
    llAttendeeList = (LinearLayout) popupView
            .findViewById(R.id.llAttendeeList);
    attendeeListView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.attendeelistview);

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 450);

    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 70);
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
    attendeeListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    attendeeListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.i("HIIII","HIII");
            String telNo = attendeeList.get(position)
                    .getTelNo();
            Intent intentDialer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:1234-5678"));
            startActivity(intentDialer);
        }
    });
}
```

When the item from listview inside a popup window is selected, I wanted to open a dialer page. However, when I tested this by putting a Log message, when I select the item from listview, it is not executing the on item selected listener.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does you adapter has any data? Where are you putting data into your adapter??

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Let me update my questiom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to another constructor with boolean parameter which is allow focusable to PopupWindow item :

[public PopupWindow (View contentView, int width, int height, boolean focusable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,450,true);
```